# Unable to get reference to clr object in Xaml for data binding

Tags: data-binding, windows-8, windows

I'm trying to follow along with the code example for data binding to a clr-object.

The example states

```
<DockPanel
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:c="clr-namespace:SDKSample">
  <DockPanel.Resources>
    <c:MyData x:Key="myDataSource"/>
  </DockPanel.Resources>
  <DockPanel.DataContext>
    <Binding Source="{StaticResource myDataSource}"/>
  </DockPanel.DataContext>
  <Button Background="{Binding Path=ColorName}"
          Width="150" Height="30">I am bound to be RED!</Button>
</DockPanel>
```

However, I seem to be having problems getting a reference the object I created (in C#) from with in my XAML

```
<Page
    x:Class="HelloWindows.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:HelloWindows"
    xmlns:src="clr-namespace:HelloWindows"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Page.Resources>
        <src:MainPage+Person x:key="person" />
    </Page.Resources>
```

Here is my C#

```
  public Person person = new Person();

    public class Person
    {
        public String name { get; set; }
    }
```

I created the "src" namespace as shown. However, Visual Studio does not recognize "Person" and wants to add "MainPage+Person" in front of it. I get the following error

> All objects added to an IDictionary must have a Key attribute or some
>   other type of key associated with them.

So I am confused about this and also about the "MainPage+Person." I would assume I need a way to tell the XAML not only the type of object, but also get a handle on the actual object I am creating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you're being challenged by slight differences in the XAML syntax for WPF and for Windows Store applications.  The DockPanel example is WPF (DockPanel isn't a native Windows Store control), and your MainPage would appear to be from a Windows Store app.

Change your namespace declaration from

```
xmlns:src="clr-namespace:HelloWindows"
```

to

```
xmlns:src="using:HelloWindows"
```

`using` is the Windows Store version of `clr-namespace`.

Comment: Thanks for you help Jim. I'm now using <local:MainPage x:Key="person" /> but I'm still not about where to link my CLR (called "person") up with XAML. I believe the "Key" it just giving the that an alias. I tried <local:person x:key="person" /> but that only seems to want to resolve to local:MainPage

Comment: <local:Person x:Key="person" /> should be working assuming the Person class resides in the HelloWindows namespace.  It sounds like you might have Person as a class nested in your MainPage class - probably not what you want here.

Comment: Yes. That was it exactly. I moved that definition outside of the MainPage class and that fixed my issue. Thanks Jim